# C++ trying to create a point from the provided coordinates

Tags: c++, pointers

For this I should be able to construct a point from a pointer (double *coordinates_) and from the number of dimensions it has (size_t dimensions_  ) which is like 2d, 3d, #d. I have this constructor function declaration called

EDIT:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
// using assert
#include <cmath>
// using fabs
#include <cstddef>
// using size_t


class Point {
  /* Used for white-box testing.
   */
  friend class PointInspector;

 public:
  /* Calculates a bounding box for the stored points and stores in the two
   * output paramters.
   *  - PRECONDITION:
   *    - all elements in the points array have the same number of dimensions
   *    - lower_left and upper_right output params have same number of
   *        dimensions as an element of points array
   *  - PARAMETERS
   *    - points: array of Point elements around which a bounding box is
   *        calculated
   *    - lower_left: output parameter to store the lower left point of a
   *        bounding-box containing all the points in the array
   *    - upper_right: output parameter to store the upper right point of a
   *        bounding-box containing all the points in the array
   *  - POSTCONDITION: the lower_left and upper_right store the lower left and
   *      upper right points of a bounding box containing all elements of the
   *      input array points.
   */
  static void CalcBoundingBox(
    const Point* points,
    size_t size,
    Point* lower_left,
    Point* upper_right);

  /* Initialization Constructors: create a point from the provided coordinates
   */
  Point();
  Point(double x, double y);
  Point(double x, double y, double z);
  Point(const double coordinates[], size_t dimensions);
  /* Copy Constructor: implements a deep copy */
  Point(const Point& that);

  /* Destructor: deletes any allocated memory
   */
  ~Point();


  /* Assignment Operator: implements a deep copy
   */
  Point &operator=(const Point& rhs); 

  /* Accessor/Mutator Operator: provides access to private member
   * - PRECONDITIONS: parameter dimension is a valid axis of the point
   * - RETURNS: reference to one of the coordinates of the point
   */
  double &operator[](size_t dimension);

  /* Equality Operator: defines points equal when the difference between
   * axes is no more than kMax_point_diff.
   * - PRECONDITIONS: points' dimensions are equal
   */
  bool operator==(const Point& rhs) const;

 private:
  static double kMax_diff;  // floating point equality

  double *coordinates_;  // coordinates of point 
  size_t dimensions_;  // dimensions of point (2d, 3d, Nd)
};
```

and here is my try at trying to construct the point.

```
void Point::CalcBoundingBox(const Point* points, size_t size, 
    Point* lower_left, Point* upper_right) {


    // find point with min x value and min y value 

    // put min x and y in the lower left output parameter

    // find point with max x value and max y value

    // put max x and y in the upper right output parameter
}
```

My question is could someone help me start out with the Bounding box. I know what I should have to find (minimum point of x and y/maximum point of x and y), but I dont know where to start with this?

I did have this code at first:

```
  dimensions_ = size;
  coordinates_ = new size_t[dimensions_];
  for (size_t i = 0; i < dimensions_; ++i) 
     *(coordinates_ + i) = *(points + i);
```

but I receive an `a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object` error. I'm wondering how I would be able to start this to ensure that all elements in the points array have the same number of dimensions and to find the min and max values of both x and y.

Comment: Also there is a friend class “PointInspector” in the same file as the constructors.

Comment: Well, there is no even minimal example provided. For example, I can't see what `dimensions_` is or where/if it is initialized. So my guess is that you don't initialize `dimensions_`.
Also - when you say "I am getting an error" - it is not clear what error and which test fails and at what point. Please add more info.

Comment: Hello. I have edited my post and included my .h file that i didn't think i needed to include, but the error i get is an seg fault error, but i dont know why. I'm trying to figure out if i created the point right from the pointer and the dimension (size) of the point.

Comment: What's your error?  Also, at minimum you need to allocate space for `coordinates_`

Comment: My error is a Segmentation Fault. I did what @AbbysSoul said to do, but still received the same error, so i'm wondering if the reference of x and y are wrong.

Comment: Well I only shoed the issue with one constructor `Point(double x, double y)`. Since there is no other code shown in the example I can assume the same issue applies to `Point(double x, double y, doubl z)`. Did you fixed that one as well?

Comment: Also, I think an array constructor `Point(const double coordinates[], size_t dimensions);` must be changed accordingly: not to re-assign from array arg passed but to copy values.

Answer (score 3):

With the extra header provided, I may to and guess that the reason for segemntation error is access to uninitialized memory.

The class `Point` declares member `coordinates_` as a pointer.
I can not see any code to allocate an array to which this pointer might be pointing. Thus I am assuming that this constructor:

```cpp
Point::Point(double x, double y) {
    coordinates_[0] = x;
    coordinates_[1] = y;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < dimensions_; ++i) {
        *(coordinates_ + i);
    }
```

Accesses a memory pointed by `coordinates_` which has not been allocated. Thus `segmentation error`

In order to resolve that issue - you may either allocate array dynamically:

```cpp
Point::Point(double x, double y) {
    dimensions_ = 2;
    coordinates_ = new double[dimensions_];
    coordinates_[0] = x;
    coordinates_[1] = y;
}
```

...and not forget to `delete` it in the destructor of `Point`.

```cpp
~Point() {
  delete coordinates_;
}
```

Or better yet - use dynamic array such as `std::vector<double>`.

Also - this loop does nothing useful. Consider removing it.

```cpp
    for (size_t i = 0; i < dimensions_; ++i) {
        *(coordinates_ + i);
    }
```

Comment: Question: Is there a way for me to assign both parameters (x and y) to different indices ([0] and [1]), respectively. Would it just be an array that the pointer would point to? Because I need x as the reference of coordinates[0] and so on.

Comment: Not sure I understood the question... But I think there is a confusion about how arrays and pointers are related in C and C++. Pointer points to address in memory. An array is an area of memory that has been allocated. Technically `pointer[1] = x` is equivalent to `*(pointer + 1) = x;`. Thus if you allocate an array with `new[]` and assign its address to `coordinates_` then you should be able to assign `coordinates_[0] = x`, `coordinates_[1] = y` and a whole lot more :)

Comment: Note - there a multiple causes for sementation failure. My answer addresses one possible option. Without the rest of the code, it is impossible to be more specific. If you still experience problem - I suggest you isolate test cases so at least you know which ones passes.

Comment: Hi, thanks again for the help last week. I was wondering I you could help me out with one more thing. So I'm trying to create a bounding box for the points in this array, but I'm wondering how I would be able to start this to ensure that all elements in the points array have the same number of dimensions and to find the min and max values of both x and y. Also, I've edited my original post to show the error, header, and .cpp file that I have.